# Carregar um combobox através da seleção de outro combobox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Ao retornar os valores no combobox, está retornando como undefined:

```
include 'relacao-cidades.php';
```

E logo abaixo o combobox que pretendo carregar os estados conforme a cidade selecionada:

```
 <select name="Estados" id="CmbCidade" class="form-control">

 </select>
```

E o Jquery que não está funcionando:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#CmbUF').change(function(e) {
            $('#CmbCidade').empty();
            var id = $(this).val();
            $.post('listar-cidades.php', {ufid:id}, function(data){
                var cmb = '<option value="">Selecione a Cidade</option>';
                $.each(data, function (index, value){
                    cmb = cmb + '<option value="' + value.cidadeid + '">' + value.cidade + '</option>';;
                });
                $('#CmbCidade').html(cmb);
            }, 'json');
        });
    });
</script>
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]) && $_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"] === "XMLHttpRequest"){
       $conexao = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','tabela') or die(mysqli_error($conexao));
        $ufid = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ufid', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
//$ufid = 48;
        if ($ufid){
            $query = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT IdCidade, Cidade FROM cidades WHERE IdCidade =".$ufid."");
            $linhas = array();
           while($jm = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                $linhas[] = $jm["Cidade"];
            }

            echo json_encode($linhas);
           }       
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tens um problemalado do servidor, e é por isso que o JavaScript não funciona.

Deves mudar

```
$linhas[] = $jm["Cidade"];
```

para

```
$linhas[] = array(
    "cidade" => $jm["Cidade"],
    "cidadeid " => $jm["IdCidade"]
);
```

para ele passar não uma array simples com o nome das cidades mas sim objetos que podes iterar e ir buscar propriedades no JavaScript mais tarde.

Comment: Perfeito Sergio. Funcionou. Muito obrigado por sua presteza.

Comment: Olá Sérgio. Não sei se eu teria que abrir mais um post, porém como agora que foi perceber isso, acredito que posso aproveitar dentro dessa dúvida. Sua ajuda está funcionando, porém agora foi perceber que o IdCidade retorna undefined. Já verifiquei no banco e a nomenclatura, assim como o valor, estão corretos.

Answer (score -2):

Muito Bom.. Funcionou Aqui      Usando Cargo e Departamento 
Porem quando uso na cidade nao esta retornando nada

```
<?php
```

include "conexao.php";

$ufid = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ufid', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
//$ufid = 48;
if ($ufid) {
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT idCidade, nomeCidade FROM tbCidade WHERE fkEstado =" . $ufid . "");
    $linhas = array();
    while ($jm = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $linhas[] = array(
            "cidade" => $jm["nomeCidade"],
            "cidadeid " => $jm["idCidade"]
        );
    }

```
echo json_encode($linhas);
```

}
?>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#carrEst').change(function(e) {
        $('#carrCid').empty();
        var id = $(this).val();
        $.post('../include/carrCid.php', {ufid:id}, function(data){
            var cmb = 'Selecione a Cidade';
            $.each(data, function (index, value){
                cmb = cmb + '' + value.cidade + '';;
            });
                $('#carrCid').html(cmb);
            }, 'json');
        });
    });